# Form for OTP entry with six single-character text fields

Tags: swift, form, ios, event-handling, cocoa

I am working on an app in which I have to pass 6 digits OTP through 6 `textFields` in which you to provide only one character and after that it automatically goes to another `textField`. I created 6 textFields outlets and used this code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

txtOTP1.delegate = self
txtOTP2.delegate = self
txtOTP3.delegate = self
txtOTP4.delegate = self
txtOTP5.delegate = self
txtOTP6.delegate = self

}
```

And I used this logic to create the functionality

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range:NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // Range.length == 1 means,clicking backspace
    if (range.length == 0){
        if textField == txtOTP1 {
            txtOTP2?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField == txtOTP2 {
            txtOTP3?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField == txtOTP3 {
            txtOTP4?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField == txtOTP4 {
            txtOTP5?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField == txtOTP5 {
            txtOTP6?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField == txtOTP6 {
            txtOTP6?.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        textField.text? = string
        return false
    }else if (range.length == 1) {
        if textField == txtOTP6 {
            txtOTP5?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField == txtOTP5 {
            txtOTP4?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField == txtOTP4 {
            txtOTP3?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField == txtOTP3 {
            txtOTP2?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField == txtOTP2 {
            txtOTP1?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        if textField == txtOTP1 {
            txtOTP1?.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        textField.text? = ""
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

But it is very long and messy. Is there anyway I can make it simple?

[image]

Comment: An array of text fields looks promising. I am not a swift person, so no review.

Comment: You can use ib oulet collection and set the tag on the text input to see which textinput is it. But i think selecting the other textbox only with comparing the tag is also longer than your code.

Comment: yes that is also a long process by using tags and compare

Answer (score 4):

Your solution to this particular problem is fine in its own way. However when it comes to scaling, it will become quite messy. Since I don't see any scope of improvement/tweaking in your approach, I suggest an alternative solution.

As pointed out in the comments, you can get what you want with **Outlet Collections**, since they are basically an array of `UIKit` objects, thus making it easy to manipulate them for our specific case.

---

### Step 1

First off, connect your textfields to an Outlet Collection, and delegates in **Interface Builder** itself *(as shown in the image below)*, which gets rid of the redundant

```
@IBOutlet var txtOTP1: UITextField!
```

and

```
txtOTP1.delegate = self
```

statements.

[image: Outlet Collection -- IB]

```
@IBOutlet var textFieldsOutletCollection: [UITextField]!
```

---

### Step 2

We are going to use a dictionary with the textfield as the `key` and its corresponding index in the outlet collection as the `value`:

```
var textFieldsIndexes:[UITextField:Int] = [:]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    for index in 0 ..< textFieldsOutletCollection.count {
        textFieldsIndexes[textFieldsOutletCollection[index]] = index
    }
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

---

### Step 3

The basic idea is, we can get the index of the textfield in our collection by supplying *(to the dictionary)* the textfield object we get in `shouldChangeCharactersIn` method, and then make the next or previous textfield the first responder:

```
enum Direction { case left, right }

func setNextResponder(_ index:Int?, direction:Direction) {

    guard let index = index else { return }

    if direction == .left {
        index == 0 ?
            (_ = textFieldsOutletCollection.first?.resignFirstResponder()) :
            (_ = textFieldsOutletCollection[(index - 1)].becomeFirstResponder())
    } else {
        index == textFieldsOutletCollection.count - 1 ?
            (_ = textFieldsOutletCollection.last?.resignFirstResponder()) :
            (_ = textFieldsOutletCollection[(index + 1)].becomeFirstResponder())
    }

}
```

---

### Step 4

Now the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` method becomes more simple and clean:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if range.length == 0 {
        setNextResponder(textFieldsIndexes[textField], direction: .right)
        textField.text = string            
        return true
    } else if range.length == 1 {
        setNextResponder(textFieldsIndexes[textField], direction: .left)
        textField.text = ""            
        return false
    }
    return false
}
```

---

### Final Code

With all the above code combined, your view controller should look like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textFieldsOutletCollection: [UITextField]!

    var textFieldsIndexes:[UITextField:Int] = [:]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for index in 0 ..< textFieldsOutletCollection.count {
            textFieldsIndexes[textFieldsOutletCollection[index]] = index
        }
    }

    enum Direction { case left, right }

    func setNextResponder(_ index:Int?, direction:Direction) {

        guard let index = index else { return }

        if direction == .left {
            index == 0 ?
                (_ = textFieldsOutletCollection.first?.resignFirstResponder()) :
                (_ = textFieldsOutletCollection[(index - 1)].becomeFirstResponder())
        } else {
            index == textFieldsOutletCollection.count - 1 ?
                (_ = textFieldsOutletCollection.last?.resignFirstResponder()) :
                (_ = textFieldsOutletCollection[(index + 1)].becomeFirstResponder())
        }

    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if range.length == 0 {
            textField.text = string
            setNextResponder(textFieldsIndexes[textField], direction: .right)
            return true
        } else if range.length == 1 {
            textField.text = ""
            setNextResponder(textFieldsIndexes[textField], direction: .left)
            return false
        }

        return false

    }

}
```

This method should theoretically work for **infinite** number of `UITextField`s with same amount of code as opposed to your approach, in which the amount of code is dependent on the number of textfields used, which is not handsome/pretty.

Comment: I tried your code but it is not working infact it can't go to the next textfield. See my above image

Comment: @V_rohit Did you properly connect all the text fields to the single outlet collection? It should work. And also make sure the delegates are set.

Comment: yes I connected all the outlets to the textfield array

Comment: delegates are set ?? do I need to create separate outlets for textfield

Comment: I’ll edit my answer to be more clear.

Comment: @V_rohit Pls refer to the image I attached to the answer. The screenshot shows all the outlets in the view controller. Make sure all delegates are set for all the 6 textfields, and that the outlet is also connected. I am using 5 textfields in my screenshot.

Comment: Okay let me try that

Comment: there are some issues i uploaded my project on GitHub https://github.com/waytorohit/OTPFIELD please check. First is entering data in first textfield it automatically add same data in second textfield

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83569/discussion-between-badhan-ganesh-and-v-rohit).

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using a single text box have the same background and then have letter spacing. This would give u less amount of code and better visibility.